# how to replace the command line argument by inputs in python?

Tags: python, input, command-line-arguments

I downloaded the code and I run it through the command-line argument, but I want to modify them with raw input, the code I used as follows (the part of the code to modify)

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--image_folder', required=True, help='path to image_folder which contains text images')
parser.add_argument('--workers', type=int, help='number of data loading workers', default=4)
parser.add_argument('--batch_size', type=int, default=192, help='input batch size')
parser.add_argument('--saved_model', required=True, help="path to saved_model to evaluation")
""" Data processing """
parser.add_argument('--batch_max_length', type=int, default=25, help='maximum-label-length')
parser.add_argument('--imgH', type=int, default=32, help='the height of the input image')
parser.add_argument('--imgW', type=int, default=100, help='the width of the input image')
parser.add_argument('--rgb', action='store_true', help='use rgb input')
parser.add_argument('--character', type=str, default='0123456789\"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS°TUV()WXY.Z', help='character label') #must be same as the characters in train.py
#'0123456789\"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS°TUV()WXY.Z'
parser.add_argument('--sensitive', action='store_true', help='for sensitive character mode')
parser.add_argument('--PAD', action='store_true', help='whether to keep ratio then pad for image resize')
""" Model Architecture """
parser.add_argument('--Transformation', type=str, required=True, help='Transformation stage. None|TPS')
parser.add_argument('--FeatureExtraction', type=str, required=True, help='FeatureExtraction stage. VGG|RCNN|ResNet')
parser.add_argument('--SequenceModeling', type=str, required=True, help='SequenceModeling stage. None|BiLSTM')
parser.add_argument('--Prediction', type=str, required=True, help='Prediction stage. CTC|Attn')
parser.add_argument('--num_fiducial', type=int, default=20, help='number of fiducial points of TPS-STN')
parser.add_argument('--input_channel', type=int, default=1, help='the number of input channel of Feature extractor')
parser.add_argument('--output_channel', type=int, default=512,
                    help='the number of output channel of Feature extractor')
parser.add_argument('--hidden_size', type=int, default=256, help='the size of the LSTM hidden state')

opt = parser.parse_args()

""" vocab / character number configuration """
if opt.sensitive:
    opt.character = string.printable[:-6]  # same with ASTER setting (use 94 char).

cudnn.benchmark = True
cudnn.deterministic = True
opt.num_gpu = torch.cuda.device_count()

demo(opt)
```

the argument I used is `python demo.py --image_folder eval --Transformation TPS --FeatureExtraction ResNet --SequenceModeling BiLSTM --Prediction Attn --saved_model saved_models/TPS-ResNet-BiLSTM-Attn-Seed1111/best_accuracy.pth`

now I want to hardcode this with direct input, I don't know how to do it, please anyone help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For each argument in argparse, it is possible to set default values so that if no flag is passed, it fallsback onto the values provided.

In your code you have this:
`parser.add_argument('--output_channel', type=int, default=512)`

Note the `default` argument.
For each of you values that you want to hardcoded, you can set them as defaults.

Answer (score 1):

you can specify default value:

E.g.

```
parser.add_argument('--workers', type=int, help='number of data loading workers', default=4)
```

The `default=4` is the hardcode value if you don't modify `--workers` in command line.

Comment: I dont want to pass arguments in this program, I desire to modify by using delcaration for each arguments i.e., parser.add_argument('--workers', type=int, help='number of data loading workers', default=4) as workers=4(normal variable), I tried but I cannot achieve it exactly

Comment: you can `print(opt)` to check what the exact value is.

Comment: yes, I tried and print(opt) gives the output as Namespace("All the above default varaiables") value printed as namespace